# How to handle MySQL slave failover in python?

Tags: python, mysql, failover

Is there a generally accepted way to handle MySQL slave db failover in python code?

Are there any good wrappers for SQLAlchemy connection pools (or other approaches) that are aware of replicas and can switch to them automatically?  Is there a standard wrapper for DB-API cursors that can do this?

I remember using a Memcached library in PHP that implemented this sort of behavior (you gave it a list of memcached hosts and it would keep track of which hosts were down).  Are there any accepted ways of doing this with python and MySQL which I am missing?